# How do i find the port to use for batteryhistorian in Docker?

Tags: docker, port

Is there a specific port for the batteryhistorian that I should use? I got it to work yesterday with the portnumber 5665 after getting it to work yesterday. Today I got the error:

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:5665 failed: port is already allocated.
```

How do I make this work again? Is there a way to see what port you should use? The documentation just says:

```
run -p <port>:9999 gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0 --port 9999
```

Which doesn't help me much.

Thanks

Comment: you already have a container which used 5665 port. please add the question your output of the command `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 0):

On your Docker host system, run the following command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 5665
```

That should show you the process that uses Port 5665. Btw, the --port 9999 refers to the inner port of your container. The documentation does not mention that you have to use a specific port, so run

```
docker run -p <port>:9999 gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0 --port 9999
```

with other ports than 5665 until you get no error message.